# applying a list to a function's arguments

Tags: list, function, f#, functional-programming

How to write a function in F# for applying a list of values to a function like the [`Apply` (@@) symbol in mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) (map elements of the list to function arguments)

for example `apply f [1;2;3]` calls `f(1,2,3)` or as in curried function application `f 1 2 3`

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the general case as you create an infinite type which is not allowed.  However, if the size of the list is known this is trivial.

Comment: This is an XY question. Rather than describing the problem you are trying to solve you have described a solution specific to another tool (Mathematica). If you gave an example of a problem that you might solve using `Apply` in Mathematica you would get better answers here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a function like `apply` that takes any F# function and an array of arguments and invokes the function via Reflection.

However, there is a good reason why this is not in the standard F# library - one of the strengths of F# (compared e.g. to Mathematica) is that it is statically typed language and can catch most potential errors at compile time. If you use something like `apply` then you'll lose this checking [because you never know if the list has the right length].

Nevertheless, here is an example of how to do this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let apply (f:obj) (args:obj[]) =
  if FSharpType.IsFunction(f.GetType()) then
    let invoke =
      f.GetType().GetMethods()
      |> Seq.find (fun mi -> mi.Name = "Invoke" && mi.GetParameters().Length = args.Length)
    invoke.Invoke(f, args)
  else failwith "Not a function"
```

Sample use looks like this:

```
let add a b = a + b;;
apply add [| 3;4 |];;
```